# Do we need get/set method for enum?

Tags: java

I have an enum like this:

```
   public enum Gender {
    FEMALE("F"), 
    MALE("M");

    private String code;

    private Gender(String code) {
        this.code= code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
       return code;
    }

    public static List<Gender> getGenders() {
        return Arrays.asList(Gender.values());
    }
}
```

Someone asked why I don't do it like this:

```
public enum Gender {
    FEMALE("F"), 
    MALE("M");

    public final String code; //change scope and put final

    private Gender(String code) {
        this.code= code;
    }

    public static List<Gender> getGenders() {
        return Arrays.asList(Gender.values());
    }
}
```

It's shorter and still keep all functionalities of that enum.

Do you think it's good idea? Does it break OOP principle?

Comment: No it doesn't break OOP anything. It breaks bean conventions. If you don't use any bean-like tools / introspectors, then the public field does work just fine.

Comment: Personally I would keep `code` private and expose a getter, for better encapsulation and greater future flexibility.

Comment: If the code could change (for example, for i18n reasons, maybe the code is loaded from a bundle) then encapsulation is valuable. Anecdotally, this sort of think almost never happens with enums...

Comment: No need to even put the character into the Enum here, in my opinion.  Have a MALE and a FEMALE without the 'F' and 'M' in the enum.

Comment: hi @EdwinBuck
Yes, we can do like this for my example but we can't avoid this completely, sometime we still need an code/key/name... for enum. :)